# JQGrid - onrowclick - jqueryPopup - MULTIPLE Query string not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a JQGrid and on rowCLick am calling this popUp dialog :

```
function InitializeDialog($element, id, c, t) {
    $element.dialog({
                     --------
                    open: function (event, ui) {
                    $element.load("/Home/Action?ID=" + id + "&category=" + c + "&title=" + t, function () {......
```

This code is not passing the all queryString but only first 2, but when I give URL like below, its working :

```
$element.load("/Home/Action?ID="+id+"&category="+c, function () {....
```

Whats issue in passing more than 2 queryString here in JQGrid , JQuery ??
Or any issue in the script above ?

Rigin

Comment: Sorry, but which relation have the question to jqGrid? There are no `onrowclick` (there are `onSelectRow`, `onRightClickRow`, `onCellSelect` and so on). So you calls `InitializeDialog` in some unclear way from some unclear callback of jqGrid. What is the problem? Do you tried just use `alert("/Home/Action?ID=" + id + "&category=" + c + "&title=" + t);` inside of `InitializeDialog`? Probably you calls the function with some wrong parameters?

Comment: What I meant is oncellSelect :

        onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e) {
            var id = $('#' + rowid).children().first().html();
            var c = $('#' + rowid).children()[1].firstChild.data;
            var t = $('#' + rowid).children()[3].firstChild.data;

            InitializeDialog($("#vIssue"), id, c, t);
             $("#vIssue").dialog("open");
        },

Comment: I should have given :
  $element.load("/Home/Action?ID=" + id + "&category=" + c + "&title=" + encodeURIComponent(t),
got an info from asp forum

Answer (score 0):

If there are any special character / any such ...
Use encoding as :

$element.load("/Home/Action?ID=" + id + "&category=" + c + "&title=" + encodeURIComponent(t),

This worked for me. Hope could be helpful for someone else